# What does this multiple ng-App code segment in AngularJS seed mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code is found in https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index.html

It looks strange to me. The code comments away all the `ng-app` away. How is AngularJS going to load the module `myApp`?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-app` directive is used to bootstrap the AngularJS app. This is the scope of the app.

[**Docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the  or  tags.

In the code above, the comments are for IE with respective version.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
```

this will only render in IE version 7. So, adding a specific class to `html` tag element. This will allow us to add styles specifically to IE-7.

Also, this is useful if you want to use some code to specifically for IE-7

Ex.

```
if ($('html').hasClass('lt-ie7')) {
    // IE 7 specific code
}
```

OR in CSS

```
.lt-ie7 mySelector {

}
```

**What is `no-js` class?**

This is a *hack* used by many developers to detect if Javascript is disabled and fallback styles to the CSS which are set from JS dynamically.

**How?**

The class is removed by using Javascript and used this class as ancestor for adding styles when Javascript is disabled.

In CSS:

```
.no-js mySelector {
    /* JS is disabled */

    /* Fallback to CSS */
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to know what `class="no-js"` mean?

Comment: `if ($('html').hasClass('lt-ie7')) {
    // IE 7 specific code
}` looks much more readable. THanks.